# How to point to a file from root directory using xampp in Linux?

Tags: php, html, linux, directory, xampp

I'm using Linux and xampp. Having trouble pointing to file directory.

So something like this works fine:

```
<?php include("/opt/lampp/htdocs/includes/navigation.html"); ?>
```

But an anchor href attribute or image src attribute won't. Object not found error 404. Example:

```
<a href="/opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php">Home</a>
```

Now heres the catch. I can use:

```
<a href="../index.php">Home</a>
```

I been at this for a day and can't find any solution. I can use plain html and css without xampp, no problems there. But I want to check my php. Any help would be appreciated. thanks. I'm quite new to code btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paths that start with a slash are called absolute. Absolute file paths in PHP source are anchored to your server's root directory, as you've discovered. So if you do this:

```
<?php include("/opt/lampp/htdocs/includes/navigation.html"); ?>
```

That refers to the actual file on your server at `/opt/lampp/htdocs/includes/navigation.html`. No surprises there.

However, absolute file paths in HTML are anchored to the web server's document root setting. You have to add the document root to the beginning of all absolute HREF paths. So if your web server has its document root set to `/opt/lampp/htdocs/`, then you do this:

```
<a href="/index.php">Home</a>
```

And that actually refers to `/opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php`. If you're unsure what your document root is set to, you can `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];`